# Touch event problem of UIPopoverController and DetailViewController in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

My iPad project used the default split view template, and now me explain the layouts.

In portrait mode, the UIPopoverController contains a UINavigationController which has a UITableView.

For the DetailViewController, it contains a UIImageView which detects touch events.

I implemented the swipe-to-delete method in the UITableView in the UIPopoverController.

However, when I swipe to delete an item in the UITableView, the underlying UIImageView also receives the swipe touch event.

How to block the underlying UIImageView to receive the touch event when UIPopoverController is visible (active) ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you could disable the by setting the property `userInteractionEnabled` with NO for your `UIImageView`. therefore your `UIImageView` will be ignored and removed from the event queue

```
@property(nonatomic, getter=isUserInteractionEnabled) BOOL userInteractionEnabled
```

So use as below

```
myImageView.userInteractionEnabled  =  NO;
```